# SQL Server Continuous Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem and I have not found a way to solve it.
I have a query that returns the following information:

```
id      date      status      ignition      
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:43.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:46.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:49.000            0      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:52.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:55.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:01.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:04.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:03.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:37.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:39.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:09:36.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:19:33.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:29:33.000            0      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:39:30.000            0      NULL
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:49:30.000            0      NULL
```

I need to transform that data result into this:

```
id      date      status      ignition      
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:43.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:46.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:49.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:52.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:58:55.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:01.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:04.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:03.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:37.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 20:59:39.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:09:36.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:19:33.000            0      Acc Off
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:29:33.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:39:30.000            1      Acc On
8B8499C5-54B0-4A78-853D-6468F6EA3132      2018-04-04 21:49:30.000            1      Acc On
```

I am trying it this way, but without satisfactory results
Any idea of how I can approach it?

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT  
        id,
        UTC_datetime, 
        ignition_on,
        descripcion,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, descripcion ORDER BY UTC_datetime) AS rnd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UTC_datetime) AS rn
    FROM  
    (
        select stat.id, stat.UTC_datetime, stat.ignition_on, ala.descripcion 
        from GEOVISTA_ACTUAL.dbo.[8DF385B2AA4F43B4A2FEC99DAAD6222F_empresadispositivostatus] stat
        outer apply
        (
            select UTC_datetime, descripcion 
            from GEOVISTA_ACTUAL.dbo.[8DF385B2AA4F43B4A2FEC99DAAD6222F_empresadispositivoalarmas] ala
            where stat.package = ala.package 
        ) as ala
        where stat.id = '8b8499c5-54b0-4a78-853d-6468f6ea3132'
    ) Final
) 

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, UTC_datetime), 0) AS UTC_datetime,
    id, 
    descripcion
FROM    
    q

GROUP BY
    id, 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, UTC_datetime), 0),
    descripcion, 
    rnd - rn
```

Comment: Your data is too big, spanning several screens, for us to see what transformation is happening.  This is unclear.

Comment: please highlight the problem rather than posting the entire data. it is very hard to read your post.

Comment: of the first set of data and I need to take all the ignition on and replicate them until the next ignition off and then the same for the off.
The second set of data is how I hope they are.
I do not know how to approach it, that's why I ask for your help in some idea

Comment: David, I was not asked to give me the answer, just to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I usually approach this by separating the problem into two parts:

1. Extract the list of state changes and construct the period for which that state is active
2. Join the original list with the state change table and extract the stored state

Part 1. is really just extracting rows with non-null Ignition column values, ordered by the date and using the LEAD() window function to get the next date. We assume the last date is active going forward. In the code below, I'm using a CTE to represent the state lookup table.

Part 2. is then a simple join to match each row in your original table with the correct period from the state table.

Once the join is complete, we can just extract the period specific state and output the correct ignition state. You can see this in action in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43656/1).

```
WITH StatusByPeriod AS (
SELECT
        Id
,       [Date] AS StartPeriod
,        CASE Ignition WHEN 'Acc Off' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Status]
,       LEAD([Date], 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS EndPeriod
FROM
        StateTable
WHERE
        Ignition IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
        StateTable.[Id]
,       StateTable.[Date]
,       StatusByPeriod.[Status]
,       CASE StatusByPeriod.[Status] WHEN 0 THEN 'Acc Off' ELSE 'Acc On'    END AS Ignition
FROM
        StateTable
JOIN    StatusByPeriod ON (
                 StatusByPeriod.[Id] = StateTable.[Id]
        AND      StatusByPeriod.StartPeriod <= StateTable.[Date]
        AND      StatusByPeriod.EndPeriod > StateTable.[Date]
        )
```